# Encode and decode string as base-32 number

Tags: python, performance, number-systems

I wrote a program that can take any English text and transform it into an integer and *vice versa*.

### My method

I use two dictionaries to map between letters and numbers.  I chose base 32 because it is a multiple of 2, so I guessed that would be easy to work with.

The pairing is

- **`0` ⟷**
- **`1` ⟷ `a`**
- ⋮
- **`26` ⟷ `z`**
- ⋮ (some other characters)
- **`31` ⟷ `⍰`** (any character not included in 0-30 is coded as 31.)

### Concerns

My current encoding method is really slow as it goes through every character and treats each as a base 32, using the reference dictionary to calculate the result.

The decoding method is also not very fast because again it uses lots of `divmod()` and the number of iterations increase with the length of the string.

How can I improve my code? (Maybe a different algorithm, design choice, other things I should try?)

I am thinking about utilizing the right shift operator or implementing classes but I am not quite sure.

---

## The code

```
import string

alpha_to_num = {
    " ":0,
    ",":27,
    ".":28,
    "!":29,
    "'":30,
    '"':30,
    "⍰":31,
    "?":31,
}
num_to_alpha = {
    0:"⎵",
    27:",",
    28:".",
    29:"!",
    30:"'",
    31:"⍰",
}
counter = 1
for o in string.ascii_lowercase:
    alpha_to_num[o] = counter
    num_to_alpha[counter] = o
    counter+=1

def encode(string:str):
    string = string.lower()
    _sum = 0
    _pow = 0
    for o in string:
        if o in alpha_to_num:
            index = alpha_to_num[o]
        else:
            index = 31
        _sum += 32**_pow*index
        _pow += 1
    return _sum
def decode(integer:int):
    string = []
    while True:
        if not integer:
            break
        integer, _chr = divmod(integer,32)
        string.append(num_to_alpha[_chr])
    return ''.join(string)

# example usage
foo  = encode("lol")
print(foo)
print(decode(foo))
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem with encoding text as an integer is that Python integers become much slower to work with as they get longer, because arbitrary-precision numbers inevitably slow as they scale.

This is why crypto algorithms such as RSA or elliptic-curve cryptography are not used directly to encrypt text, but instead operate on the shorter values that hold symmetric-encryption keys, and those keys are used for the actual encryption of the text.

---

A specific problem occurs here:

```
_pow = 0
for o in string:
    ⋮
    _sum += 32**_pow*index
    _pow += 1
```

Instead of computing `32**_pow` from scratch each time around the loop, it's more efficient to remember that value and multiply it by 32 each time:

```
multiplier = 1
for o in string:
    ⋮
    sum += multiplier * index
    multiplier *= 32
```

This still won't eliminate the inefficiencies of using big integers, though.

---

Some other issues:

- Use whitespace around operators.  `counter+=1` shouldn't be packed together like that; it makes it hard to read for Python people.  `32**_pow*index` is particularly hard to unpack!
- Don't use initial underscore for local variables.  There are Python conventions for using initial underscore in class members, so they shouldn't be used in other places.  Other variable names seem mostly okay (although `string` is a poor choice, as it's also the name of a data type).
- Use a plain array type (probably a tuple) for mapping *from* integer.
- Use a `defaultdict` (or `dict.get()` with a default) to avoid throwing an exception when encoding text with a character (such as `@`) that isn't in `alpha_to_num`.
- <s>Instead of gathering characters into a list, and then `join()`ing them into a string, why not gather into a string directly?</s>
- A string that ends with spaces will lose them in the round-trip.  Think about how you could avoid that.

Comment: Gather into a list and then using `join` is the preferred way to build strings. Using `+=` on a string in a loop generally results in quadratic runtime. In some cases, CPython can optimise it in a way that results in a linear runtime, but it's best not to depend on that.

Comment: How does `list.append()` avoid the quadratic performance problem that affects `string.__iadd__()`?  I would have thought them to have similar implementations, and now I'm intrigued.

Comment: Because in Python lists are mutable, if you call `append`, lists can allocate more memory than required on the assumption it may be used later, which if you append items in a loop means you need significantly fewer reallocations. So a single call to `list.append` may or may not be (relatively) expensive, but the amortized time for that method is O(1), while `s1 += s2` where they are both strings always needs a reallocation, which is at least O(len(s1 + s2)).

Comment: Thanks Jasmijn - that's a good explanation.  I'd forgotten that Python strings are immutable (perhaps I've done too much C++ lately).

Answer (score 4):

## Base-32 to Integer

### Enumerate

Your loop ...

```
    _sum = 0
    _pow = 0
    for o in string:
        if o in alpha_to_num:
            index = alpha_to_num[o]
        else:
            index = 31
        _sum += 32**_pow*index
        _pow += 1
```

... can be greatly simplified.  First, instead of manually maintaining the `_pow` counter, use Python's `enumerate` method, which does this for you.

```
    _sum = 0
    for _pow, o in enumerate(string):
        if o in alpha_to_num:
            index = alpha_to_num[o]
        else:
            index = 31
        _sum += 32**_pow*index
```

### get with default

Next, use a `dict.get(key [,default])` to eliminate the `if o in alpha_to_num: ... else: ...` statement.

```
    _sum = 0
    for _pow, o in enumerate(string):
        index = alpha_to_num.get(o, 31)
        _sum += 32**_pow*index
```

### sum

Finally, you have a sum of a simple loop iteration, so we can now replace this with a single `sum(...)` statement:

```
    _sum = sum(32 ** _pow * alpha_to_num.get(o, 31) for _pow, o in enumerate(string))
```

### built-in

Python has a built-in function for converting base-2 through base-36 strings into integers.  It is the `int(value, base)` function.  If we passed in a suitable value, then Python will perform the required \$\Sigma_i(d_i * 32^i)\$ calculation itself.

### Reworked code

First, you want to transform your input string into a base-32 equivalent string according to the encoding:

`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,.!'?` ⇒ `0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv`

Plus uppercase letters to the same values as the lowercase ones, plus double-quote to the same as a single-quote, plus any unknown values to the equivalent as the question-mark.  The [`str.translate(table)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20translate#str.translate) built-in method will do this for us in one step, provided we give it the proper table.  The table must map from the ordinal character values to the replacement strings.  We'll use a `defaultdict` to return `'v'` (the encoding for a `'?'`) for any unknown characters.

```
from collections import defaultdict

PLAIN = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,.!'?"
CRYPT = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv"

ENCODE = defaultdict(lambda: 'v')
ENCODE.update((ord(c), p) for c, p in zip(PLAIN, CRYPT))
ENCODE.update((ord(c), p) for c, p in zip(PLAIN.upper(), CRYPT))
ENCODE[ord('"')] = 'u'             # Encode double-quote to same as single quote.

def encode(msg: str) -> int:
    encoded = msg.translate(ENCODE)
    ...
```

With the string properly translated to a base-32 string, we can now use `int(..., 32)` to convert it to an integer.  The only catch is we need to reverse the string, since the original `encode` method uses a little-endian base-32 to integer conversion.

```
    return int(encoded[::-1], 32)
```

**Update**

The above code will crash with a `ValueError` if given an empty string.  We can prevent this by changing `encoded` to `"0"` when encoding an empty string.

```
    encoded = msg.translate(ENCODE) or "0"
```

## Integer to Base-32

Unfortunately, there is no simple int-to-base-n string conversion function built-in to Python.  If there was, we could use the same `str.translate(table)` function to convert it to the desired output text.  We can even use the [`str.maketrans(x[, y[, z]])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20translate#str.maketrans) to create the necessary table for us, because we have no infinite set of unknown values to convert to a specific value.

```
CRYPT = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv"
KEY32 = "⎵abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,.!'⍰"

DECODE = str.maketrans(CRYPT, KEY32)

def decode(code: int) -> str:
    encoded = ...
    return encoded[::-1].translate(DECODE)
```

I said no ***simple*** int-to-base-***n*** string conversion function built-in to Python.  There are base32 encoding and decoding functions built-in to the `base64` standard library.  We can use that to do the heavy lifting.

But first, we need to know how long our message is going to be ... which is the number of 5-bit groups in the integer message:

```
    length = (code.bit_length() + 4) // 5
```

Then we'll need to pad the message to an integral number of bytes.

```
    bits = 5 * length
    if bits % 8 != 0:
        pad = 8 - bits % 8
        bits += pad
        code <<= pad
```

At this point, we can turn the integer into a series of bytes:

```
    data = code.to_bytes(bits // 8, 'big')
```

Now we can use the [`base64.b32hexencode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html?highlight=b32hexencode#base64.b32hexencode) method to convert that into a series of characters `0`-`9` and `A`-`V` representing 5-bit groupings of those bytes.  The data is padded with equal characters (`=`) at the end to ensure a consistent multiple of 40 bit structure, so we need to truncate the result to `length` characters to get rid of the padding.  Also, `b32hexencode` uses uppercase characters, where as we want lowercase, so we need to call `.lower()` on the result.  Finally, the output is a `bytes` object where as we desire a `str`, so we'll want to `.decode("utf-8")` the result:

```
    encoded = base64.b32hexencode(data)[:length].lower().decode("utf-8")
```

As I said, it wasn't simple.

## Reworked code

Changing the `CRYPT` to uppercase allows us to remove a `.lower()` call, for slightly simpler code.

```
from base64 import b32hexencode
from collections import defaultdict

PLAIN = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,.!'?"
CRYPT = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV"
KEY32 = "⎵abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,.!'⍰"

ENCODE = defaultdict(lambda: 'V')
ENCODE.update((ord(c), p) for c, p in zip(PLAIN, CRYPT))
ENCODE.update((ord(c), p) for c, p in zip(PLAIN.upper(), CRYPT))
ENCODE[ord('"')] = 'U'

DECODE = str.maketrans(CRYPT, KEY32)

def encode(msg: str) -> int:
    encoded = msg.translate(ENCODE) or "0"
    return int(encoded[::-1], 32)

def decode(code: int) -> str:
    length = (code.bit_length() + 4) // 5

    bits = 5 * length
    if bits % 8 != 0:
        pad = 8 - bits % 8
        bits += pad
        code <<= pad
        
    data = code.to_bytes(bits // 8, 'big')
    encoded = b32hexencode(data)[:length].decode("utf-8")
    
    return encoded[::-1].translate(DECODE)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    msg = '''The quick "brown" fox jumped 'over' the lazy dog!'''
    code = encode(msg)
    decrypted = decode(code)
    print(code)
    print(decrypted)

    from timeit import timeit
    t_enc = timeit('encode(msg)', globals=globals())
    print(f"Encryption takes: {t_enc:.2f} µs")
    t_dec = timeit('decode(code)', globals=globals())
    print(f"Decryption takes: {t_dec:.2f} µs")
```

Output:

```
51651161261624696839988483915180468301590365415316947842058570259607065876
the⎵quick⎵'brown'⎵fox⎵jumped⎵'over'⎵the⎵lazy⎵dog!
Encryption takes: 1.54 µs
Decryption takes: 7.78 µs
```